# How to Pass List<Object> to SOAP API as a request

Tags: android, soap, soapui, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

**How to Pass List to SOAP API request from android**

I know how to pass normal object, but at the time of passing the List I'm getting  following exception *Unable to cast object of type `'GTCFWebServices.Models.ToEmail'` to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GTCFWebServices.Models.ToEmail]`'.*
This is expected soap `xml` request I need to pass `List< ToEmail >` as a request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:gtc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GTCFWebServices.Models">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SendEmailNotificationToScannedUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:fromEmail>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:ActivationCode>6wDQ8</gtc:ActivationCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:Email>?</gtc:Email>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:IsEmailHasToSent>true</gtc:IsEmailHasToSent>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:Name>Snehal Jadhav</gtc:Name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:PhoneNumber>?</gtc:PhoneNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:ProfileImageName>?</gtc:ProfileImageName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:UniversityImageName>?</gtc:UniversityImageName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <gtc:UniversityName>?</gtc:UniversityName>
         </tem:fromEmail>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:scannedUsers>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <gtc:ToEmail>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gtc:Body>body</gtc:Body>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gtc:CC>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <gtc:Contact>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <gtc:Email>?</gtc:Email>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <gtc:FirstName>?</gtc:FirstName>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <gtc:LastName>?</gtc:LastName>
                  </gtc:Contact>
               </gtc:CC>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gtc:ScannedUserId>1</gtc:ScannedUserId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gtc:Subject>?</gtc:Subject>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gtc:To>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <gtc:Contact>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <gtc:Email>?</gtc:Email>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <gtc:FirstName>?</gtc:FirstName>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <gtc:LastName>?</gtc:LastName>
                  </gtc:Contact>
               </gtc:To>
            </gtc:ToEmail>
         </tem:scannedUsers>
      </tem:SendEmailNotificationToScannedUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please improve the formatting of your question using the text editor for better readability

Comment: Getting this exception:
SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:InternalServiceFault' faultstring: 'Unable to cast object of type 'GTCFWebServices.Models.ToEmail' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GTCFWebServices.Models.ToEmail]'.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@d553223

Comment: Please Add some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to pass complex object like a list of complex object as a parameter in SOAP request.

Finally, I passed String concatenating with, (comma) for a list and then API side we separated it and created a list.